# Java Scanner reading special formatted lines

Tags: java, string

How can I read a String (below) and replace the `%rackname` or `%sysname` with new text

```
KW Actual `%rackname`    -> KW Actual THE RACK NAME
KW Difference `%rackname`-> KW Actual THE RACK NAME
KW Predicted `%rackname` -> KW Actual THE RACK NAME

Loads Capacity `%sysname`          -> Loads Capacity SYS NAME
Loads Cost Difference `%sysname`   -> Loads Cost Difference SYS NAME
Loads EEPR `%sysname`              -> Loads EEPR SYS NAME
```

I need to apply this formatting to all strings in an arraylist, and some strings will have multiple variables to replace.

What is the best way to find these replaceable fields for these lists.

My first thought was using a Scanner to scan through a string using next(), if i find a word starting with a ` i read to the end of string and figure out what the field is to replace.

```
List<String []> vars = new ArrayList<String[]>() {};
    int numfans, numsg, numcomp, numsys;
    String [] newString;
    String temp;
    Scanner scan;
    for(int i = 0; i < numRacks; i++){
        // do all racks

        for(String s: rackStr){
            newString = new String[1];                
            scan = new Scanner(s);
            while(scan.hasNext()){
                temp = scan.next();
                if(temp.startsWith("`") && temp.endsWith("`")){
                    System.out.println("Temp: " + temp);
                    System.out.println("Success");                        
                    newString[0] += findVar(temp);
                }else {
                    newString[0] += temp;
                }
            }
            vars.add(newString);
        }
```

I figured this is probably horrible if i have to create a new scanner for every string in the multiple arraylists i will have.

Edit - Ok so str.replaceAll(); is such an easier solution /facepalm

Comment: Scanner is for reading and parsing, not for replacing. The String class already has decent methods for replacing -- why not use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.replaceAll` to replace patterns in a string, for example:

```
str = str.replaceAll("`%rackname`", "THE RACK NAME");
str = str.replaceAll("`%sysname`", "SYS NAME");
```

Comment: Wow... how did I not see this function